# How to place the UIImageView at the half of another view in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, constraints, uistoryboard

I want to place an `UIImageView` at the half of an another `UIView`. I have set the constraints like this:

[image: Constraints Settings]

I need the square image view to be at the half of the orange `UIView` . The above position of `UIImageView` is correct but it slightly moves up in 6 and SE screens.
Please look at the screenshots:
[image: See the square screenshot it has moved up in SE]

[image]
[image]

Why it is happening and how to prevent the `UIImageView` from moving up ? Do we need some other constraints?

What should be the constraints for the Green `UIButton` Placed to the right side of the `UIImageView`?

[image: UIButton Green color]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to remove your `top space constraint`, then you need add a constraint between your `UIImageView` and your redView, right click and drag to your red view and select align to to Top, later you need to change the first item from `.top` to `.centerY`, and add a multiplier value of 1 to be center in your red bottom edge

One Picture worth more than 1000 words

[image]

## Second requirement

In your second requirement, you need add an helper view I named it `guideView` this view background will be `.clear` and `userInteraction` will be disabled, then guideView will have `.top` and `.bottom` constraints to your `UIImageView` .top and .bottom also will have trailing space to superView with constant 0 and leading space to  your `UIImageView` with constant 0, as shows this image, then your desired green view go inside of `guideView` and will be aligned center in Vertical and Horizontal to superview and height and width with fixed values and that is all

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: later you need to change the second item from top to bottom ?? How to do this?

Comment: @ReinierMelien Sorry i had a design change please see my updated question with screenshots

Comment: @ReinierMelien Great it works. I have a small UIButton to the right side of the UIImageView. What should be the constraints for it?

Comment: Please see the Updated question. Please help for this too . I shall approve the answer

Comment: You want your green view center in the space or separated by x points from your UIImageView? @ChelseaShawra

Comment: Centre in space :) Sorry for late reply

Comment: @ChelseaShawra I am glad to help you!, happy coding and best regards

Comment: @ChelseaShawra rmelian2014@gmail.com, is my slack

Answer (score 1):

It can actually be done with a single constraint. Just align the center of both your views like this:

[image]

If you also look at the remaining constraints, the original view must be already properly constrained, the second view that have to be aligned to the original requires width and height provided and also position of the other axis. In this case where Vertical centers are align you will need to provide a X position.

Therefore if you want the views instead be aligned one above the other, align the Horizontal Centers instead and provide the Y position of the views.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it programmatically. This will always center the image view on the top edge of the view, with half above and half below.

First, make outlets for the UIImageView and for the UIView.

Then:

`[imageViewOutlet setCenter:CGPointMake(viewOutlet.frame.size.width/2, viewOutlet.frame.origin.y)]`